# Laravel validator's equivalent of isset()

Tags: laravel

In my `FormRequest` I need to validate, if selected category is actually present in the categories array.

I solved my problem with `withValidator` method, where I manually check if the category is present.

However, I feel like there must be a nicer way of doing this. I went over [validation documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules), but could not find my fit.

Has anyone tackled this problem, or do you have an idea how to do this better?

Thank you.

```
class StoreWarehouseItemRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
       return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required|integer',
            'specification' => 'nullable|string',
            'recipient' => 'nullable|string',
            'unit' => 'nullable|string',
            'sellers_code' => 'nullable|string',
            'note' => 'nullable|string',
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
    {
       $cat = $validator->getData()['category'];
       $cats = WarehouseItem::CATEGORIES;
       $validator->after(
          function ($validator) use ($cat, $cats) {
             if (!isset($cats[$cat])) {
                $validator->errors()->add('category', 'Kategória musí byť vybraná zo zoznamu.');
             }
          }
       );                            
    }
}
```

Comment: You can manually define a list of values and use the `in` rule: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in, or if the values come from the database, you'd use the `exists` rule: `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Laravel's `in:foo,bar` validator.

```php
return [
    'name' => 'required',
    'category' => ['required', 'integer', Rule::in(WarehouseItem::CATEGORIES)],
    'specification' => 'nullable|string',
    'recipient' => 'nullable|string',
    'unit' => 'nullable|string',
    'sellers_code' => 'nullable|string',
    'note' => 'nullable|string',
];
```

Additionally, if you are looking if the key exists in the `WarehouseItem::CATEGORIES` array, you can do `array_flip(WarehouseItem::CATEGORIES)` on it.

Comment: yes, the `array_flip()` helped it to perfection. thank you.